# How to calculate the expectation and variance of a complex probability distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Assuming that the continuous random variables `X1` and `X2` are independent of each other, and the variances exist, the probability densities of `X1` and `X2` are $f_{1}(x)$
and $f_{2}(x)$, the probability density of random variable $Y_{1}$ is $f_{Y_{1}}(y)=\frac{1}{2}\left[f_{1}(y)+f_{2 }(y)\right]$, random variable\mathrm${Y}_{2}=
  \frac{1}{2}\left(X_{1}+X_{2}\right)$. Which of the following statements is correct (the answer is `D`)?

$$\begin{array}{c}
&(A)&  E Y_{1}>E Y_{2}, D Y_{1}>D Y_{2} 
&(B)&  E Y_{1}=E Y_{2}, D Y_{1}=D Y_{2} \\
&(C)&  E Y_{1}=E Y_{2}, D Y_{1}<D Y_{2} 
&(D)&  E Y_{1}=E Y_{2}, D Y_{1}>D Y_{2} 
\end{array}$$

When I use the normal distribution to verify the `D` option, the following code keeps running:

```
Y1 = ProbabilityDistribution[(1/
     2) (PDF[NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], x] + 
     PDF[NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2], x]), {x, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}]


Expectation[Y1, Y1 \[Distributed] Y1]
Variance[Y1]
Y2 = TransformedDistribution[
  1/2 (x1 + x2), {x1 \[Distributed] 
    NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], 
   x2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2]}]
Expectation[Y2, Y2 \[Distributed] Y2]
Variance[Y2]
```

How can I improve the code to get the desired result?

Comment: Ask it at https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @user64494 Thank you very much for your advice. I'd like to take a chance to see if anyone can solve this problem skillfully with Mathematica.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` does nothing if `f[x]` is not specified.

Comment: Just for sportive interest, I tried it in Maple by `with(Statistics);
x1 := RandomVariable(Distribution(PDF = (x -> f__1(x))));
x2 := RandomVariable(Distribution(PDF = (x -> f__2(x))));
Y__1 := RandomVariable(Distribution(PDF = (x -> 1/2*f__1(x) + 1/2*f__2(x))));
Y__2 := (x1 + x2)/2;`
The commands    `IntegrationTools:-Expand(Mean(Y__1))` and `IntegrationTools:-Expand(Mean(Y__1))` confirm the equality of the means. However, `Variance(Y__1)` and `Variance(Y__2)` strongly differ so I don't see how to compare those in Maple and by hand.

Comment: The notion of a continuous random variable is useless in probability. In fact, absolutely continuous random variables are used. See https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Continuous_distribution for info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

In defining `Y1` you need to specify the assumptions needed to make the distribution valid.

```
Y1 = ProbabilityDistribution[
   (1/2) (PDF[NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], x] +
      PDF[NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2], x]),
   {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> {σ1 > 0, σ2 > 0}];

Mean[Y1]

(* (μ1 + μ2)/2 *)
```

which is equivalent to

```
Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] Y1]

(* (μ1 + μ2)/2 *)
```

Note that you cannot use the distribution as a variable.

```
Variance[Y1]

(* 1/4 ((μ1 - μ2)^2 + 2 (σ1^2 + σ2^2)) *)

Y2 = TransformedDistribution[
  1/2 (x1 + x2), {x1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], 
   x2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2]}]

(* NormalDistribution[μ1/2 + μ2/2, Sqrt[σ1^2/4 + σ2^2/4]] *)

Mean[Y2] // Simplify

(* (μ1 + μ2)/2 *)

Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] Y2]

(* (μ1 + μ2)/2 *)

Variance[Y2] // Simplify

(* 1/4 (σ1^2 + σ2^2) *)
```

Comment: Note that `Y1` can be represented using `MixtureDistribution[]`: `Y1 = MixtureDistribution[{1/2, 1/2}, {NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2]}]`